# Combining two Coq hypotheses

Tags: coq

So I have two hypotheses, one that is `h : A -> B`, and the other which is `h2 : A`. How can I get `h3 : B` to appear in my hypotheses?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
pose proof (h h2) as h3.
```

introduces `h3 : B` as a new hypothesis,

```
specialize (h h2).
```

modifies `h : A -> B` into `h : B` -- this can be useful if you won't need `h` later, and symmetrically,

```
apply h in h2.
```

converts `h2 : A` into `h2 : B`.

Another (not very convenient) way would be to

```
assert B as h3 by exact (h h2).
```

That's what the `pose proof` variant is equivalent to.

Also, in a simple case like the following, you can solve your goal without introducing a new hypothesis:

```
Goal forall (A B : Prop), (A -> B) -> A -> B.
  intros A B h h2.
  apply (h h2).
Qed.
```

Comment: You forgot my favorite! `apply in`

Comment: @Zimmi48 Thanks for the reminder! I've edited the answer to include `apply in`.